# How to find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1\frac{x^ne^x}{1 +e^x}dx$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Find the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1\frac{x^ne^x}{1 +e^x}dx
$$

By intuition, I can guess the answer is $0$, but I have no idea how to start to prove it.

What I have tried is using the mean value theorem. There exists $c \in (0, 1)$:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1\frac{x^ne^x}{1 +e^x}dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{c^ne^c}{1 +e^c}
$$
and I don't see how I should continue from here.

Comment: Try the dominant convergence theorem.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @BiAo the $e^c/(1+e^c)$ is a constant and since $0<c<1$ then $c^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Pixel The $c$ will tipically depend on $n$. What if $c$ approaches $1$? For example $c \sim 1-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Gary yes that does seem problematic. I tried some substitutions but the carpet still doesn't fit. A $1-\varepsilon$ argument may work as DonAntonio mentioned, but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From
$$
0\le \int_0^1{\frac{x^ne^x}{1+e^x}}dx=\int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{1+e^{-x}}}dx\le \int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{1}}dx=\int_0^1{x^n}dx
$$
From the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), take limits on both sides and we get
$$
0\le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1{\frac{x^ne^x}{1+e^x}}dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1{\frac{x^n}{1+e^{-x}}}dx\le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1{x^n}dx=0
$$
and thus
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1\frac{x^ne^x}{1 +e^x}dx=0
$$

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$
0 < \frac{{\mathrm{e}^x }}{{1 + \mathrm{e}^x }} < 1
$$
for $0<x<1$, thus
$$
0 < \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^n \mathrm{e}^x }}{{1 + \mathrm{e}^x }}\mathrm{d}x}  < \int_0^1 {x^n \mathrm{d}x}  = \frac{1}{{n + 1}}.
$$
Consequently, by the squeeze theorem,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^n \mathrm{e}^x }}{{1 + \mathrm{e}^x }}\mathrm{d}x}  = 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the integrand is a continuous function, the mean value theorem for integrals tells us that there exists $\;0<c<1\;$ s.t.

$$\int_0^1x^n\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\,dx=c^n\frac{e^c}{1+e^c}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

since $\;c^n\to 0\;$ and $\;0\le \cfrac{e^x}{1+e^x}\le 1\;$ is bounded.

Comment: The $c$ will tipically depend on $n$. What if $c$ approaches $1$? For example $c \sim 1-\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Gary Very good point, though taking the upper limit as $\;1-\epsilon\;$ could solve the problem...perhaps. I shall take a second thought on this one. Observe that $\;c_n\to 1\;$ is the only problem here. Any other behaviour, like swinging away from $\;1\;$  or converging to some $\;h\in [0,1)\;$  would yield the same result as above.